# How do I delete an element from an array and store that array back into chrome.storage.local?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

Im building a chrome extension that lets you save/store links. I store them in an array which is saved inside the chrome local storage.

Users also have the ability to delete a certain item thats stored, using a delete button that is next to their link.

The issue is that the last element of the list is always deleted no matter which item the user deletes.

```
$("ul").on("click", ".removeButton", function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get({bookmarks: []}, function(data) {
        var bookmarks = data.bookmarks;
        bookmarks.splice($(this).parent().index(), 1);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ bookmarks: bookmarks}, function() {
            chrome.storage.local.get('bookmarks', function(data) {
                console.log(data.bookmarks)
            })
        });
    })
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Comment: what's the value of `$(this).parent().index()` - I think you expect `this` to be something else

Comment: it's the index of where the item is in the array

Comment: I didn't ask for a description, I asked what the **value** actually is - try changing `function(data) {` to `(data) => {`

Comment: well the value changes based on which link you're deleting but its a number. Same result even with (data) =>

Comment: you used `console.log` to confirm this? If not, I asked what the value **is**, not what you think it is - and I doubt `$(this)` has anything to do with the element that has been clicked - because as I said, `this` is not likely to be what you think it is

Comment: you're right its not what I expected, it's -1 for some reason. "$(this).parent().remove();" at the end still works how it's supposed to though.

Comment: `this` in `$(this).parent().remove();` will naturally be correct given the scope of that statement - I'm surprised that `(data) => {` didn't help though - you did replace the FIRST occurrence not the second?

Comment: of course, I assume `$(this).parent().index()` will return what you expect it to return, without any hint of HTML, it's an assumption that it does what you think it does

Comment: yeah I removed the first one, but you just helped me figure out how to fix it. Since the scope of the bottom line was correct, I created a variable for the index before chrome.storage.local.get({bookmarks: []}, function(data). Thanks so much